# Parsing tag data from HTML using JSoup in Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How would I parse *46389333*  out of the following html?

```
 <a href="/exampleTweet/status/46389333"
```

I'm using JSoup, and I can parse text, tags, and other values obviously. But I can't quite figure out how to parse out that value. Even if I could only parse out /exampleTweet/status/46389333, then at least I could parse that string, a lot easier. Problem is, the number changes, and so does *exampleTweet* obviously. Status stays there though, so maybe I could use that somehow? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to go with just using the Element's "toString()" function, and then delimiting that string. Hope this helps someone out in the future!